# Write JSON object to Windows Phone Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, json.net, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to save a `JSON` object that is returned from `Azure Mobile Services` to the Windows Phone `isolated storage`. I've started with the code below, but I'm not entirely sure how to actually write the file to Isolated Storage or what format to save it in (XML, TXT, etc.).

```
        string offlineData = Path.Combine("WPTracker", "Offline");
        string offlineDataFile = Path.Combine(offlineData, "phones.xml");
        var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        //Query
        try
        {
            phoneList = await phoneTable
                .Where(PhoneItem => PhoneItem.Publish == true)
                .OrderBy(PhoneItem => PhoneItem.FullName)
                .ToListAsync();
        }
        catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException f)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(f.Response.Content.ToString(),
                    string.Format("{0} (HTTP {1})",
                    f.Response.Content,
                    f.Response.StatusCode), MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }

        //Write
        IsolatedStorageFileStream dataFile = null;
        dataFile = store.OpenFile(offlineDataFile, FileMode.Create);
        DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(IEnumerable<Phones>));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
        JsonWriter jWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw);

        ser.WriteObject(dataFile, phoneList);
        dataFile.Close();
```

Any suggestions? :)

### Edit

I decided to write the data to Isolated Storage using a JSON file, rather than XML. This was because my data from Azure Mobile Services is being sent in JSON. No need to convert it to XML. A link can be found below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A guide on how to write a JSON object to isolated storage in Windows Phone can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/09/04/how-to-store-json-data-in-windows-phone-8.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Here's example how to save json and then how to retrieve it.

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    const string MyDirectory = "offline";
    readonly string _offlineDataFile = Path.Combine(MyDirectory, "phones.json");
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var data = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://www.tapanila.net/api/get_recent_posts/");
        var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        if (!store.DirectoryExists(MyDirectory))
        {
            store.CreateDirectory(MyDirectory);
        }


        using (var fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(_offlineDataFile, FileMode.Create, store))
        {
            using (var stream = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
            {
                stream.Write(data);
            }
        }
        LoadOffline();
    }

    private void LoadOffline()
    {
        var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        using (var fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(_offlineDataFile, FileMode.Open, store))
        {
            using (var stream = new StreamReader(fileStream))
            {
               var data = stream.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure the saving of the JSON file worked correctly. I JSON file contains the following: `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.TotalCountList`1[WPTracker.ViewModels.Phones.Phones]`